# Handling any json that has key value pairs and the values are saved as github secrets dyamically in Github actions / Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, github, github-actions

I would be having random json files with different key value pairs , which has the azure app settings per service per project. Note that the key value pairs and the numver of key value pairs can change.

I want to store the value as GITHUB secrets with the same name as the Key , and i am looking for a way to dynamically update the json as $key = ${{secrets.[$key] }} , something like this for each key in Json file using powershell

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically retrieve GitHub Actions secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255989/dynamically-retrieve-github-actions-secret)

Comment: In the link i need to know the name of the KEY in advance but in my case i dont know the name of the key , all i know is the value is stored in github with the same name as the key and i need to assign this value to the key

Comment: And the update need to be done inside a JSON file

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an example JSON file. I can imagine that it's possible to programmatically extract all the secret names using jq, and then apply the techniques from the other answer.