# Personal GitHub secrets for each dev who can push to repo

Tags: github, github-actions

In our organization we have a repo on GitHub, multiple devs can push to it. That repo uses a GitHub Actions workflow which needs a secret token to work. However, I cannot provide a organization-wide token on GitHub for that action, since every developer who can push to that repo has their own personal token. How can I allow each of our devs to provide their own personal token to the GitHub Actions workflow on a git push?

Comment: _"I cannot provide a organization-wide token on GitHub for that action, since every developer who can push to that repo has their own personal token"_ - I don't see how those correlate, devs can have their own tokens and CI can use another token.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I don't get it. How can a dev set a secret on his Github account, under a certain name, so that when the CI action is being called it would use the dev's secret then?

Comment: It could be useful to share more context: Why do you need to use the devs token instead of an organization-wide token?

Comment: _Pick one_, and use it per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow

Comment: @GuiFalourd Part of the GitHub Action is the call of 3rd party tool. That tool needs a token (secret) when being called. But each dev has their own such token. It's not a single shared token for the whole company.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But how can I pick one? The 3rd party tool used in the GitHub Action requires a secret token, but each developer has their own token.

Comment: Do _you_ have one? Can't you use that? Could you ask the vendor for an additional "service"/"machine" token?

Comment: This seems quite specific. If you can't use an organization-wide token as a secret, you would need a way to retrieve the dev token through the workflow run, for example consuming an API. Is it possible?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's exactly my point and the reason for asking this question - there is no single token to use in this case, as each developer has his own secret token, that's how the 3rd party recognizes each developer account.

Comment: @GuiFalourd That's why I am asking here. So there is no "out of the box" solution on Github for this problem?

Comment: No, you would need a customized solution here.

Comment: It sounds like there are _several_ single tokens. Why can't you pick one - why (and to whom) does it matter which dev's account the CI runs appear to be under? You can provide specific inputs to a workflow when you manually trigger it, but then you don't get automatic execution on push (and I'm not sure they're treated as secrets).

Comment: @jonrsharpe This 3rd party tool that is being called from the CI action, each of our devs has their own account with that tool. So when the CI action calls that 3rd party tool, it needs to authenticat with that tool using a secret token. And again, each dev has a personal token, which needs to be used for this authentication.

Comment: `and I'm not sure they're treated as secrets` (they aren't )

Comment: OK there's only so many times I can ask the same question.

Comment: With the whole context explained, I agree with `jonrsharpe` when he suggested that the vendor could provide an additional "service"/"machine" token for this specific scenario. Otherwise you will need a way to get the dev token based on an input (from context, manually or through API) and that might not be trivial to configure neither very secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most trivial solution would be to obtain and configure a repository-wide "machine" or "bot" token and configure that as a repository secret, using it to pass to the appropriate job step.

Alternatively, you let your developers configure a pre-push hook, so they can run the tool that now runs in CI locally instead. This requires configuration and discipline for each repository and developer.

The worst solution, but the one you seem to be aiming at, would be to configure *each* developer's token as repository secret, including their name, e.g. `TOOL_TOKEN_MATTHIAS`.

Then on push, you obtain the `github.event.pusher.name`, and [using format()]]([Dynamically retrieve GitHub Actions secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255989/dynamically-retrieve-github-actions-secret)), look up the appropriate secret, something like this:

```
secrets[format('TOOL_TOKEN_{0}', github.event.pusher.name)]
```

This too will require configuration and discipline, and is fragile.

Comment: Thanks for multiple ideas. Unfortunately I cannot use one "machine" token, because each dev uses his own personal environment in that 3rd party tool that is called from the CI action. The 2nd approach is also not an option, since the CI action has to run on a server with multiple GPUs for AI training. Thanks for the 3rd approach, I understand it might be a fragile solution, but it should work for us. I could also think of having each dev's token somewhere in the repo as an alternative ...