# Dynamically set variable names in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to dynamically set/access a variable name in github actions?

I have the below workflow:

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env: 
        description: environment

jobs:
 deploy:
 steps: 
   uses: actions/checkout@v2
   - name: access db  
     uses: db_action
      with: 
       username: ${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}
       password: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD_${{ inputs.env }} }}
```

I'm trying to get the secret variable for password (Which can be DB_PASSWORD_E1 or DB_PASSWORD_E2) dynamically. Is this possible?

Comment: maybe using `${{ }}` is your solution, please check my answer !

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. The first one corresponds to [Dynamically retrieve GitHub Actions secret](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61255989/3266847): you have to use the [`format` function](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) to build the key for the secret you want to look up, and use the format `secrets[<key>]` to reference the key. Like this:

```yaml
- name: access db  
  uses: db_action
  with: 
    username: ${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets[format('DB_PASSWORD_{0}', inputs.env)] }}
```

However, I believe a more idiomatic solution would be to use [environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-environments-for-jobs). Create an environment for each possible value of `inputs.env`, and store the secret under, say `PASSWORD` for each environment. Then, your workflow looks like this:

```yaml
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env: 
        description: environment

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    environment: ${{ inputs.env }}
    steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.3
      - name: access db  
        uses: db_action
        with: 
          username: ${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

The important bit is the `environment` value on the job: `secrets.PASSWORD` will be whatever the corresponding environment secret is.