# Dynamic Github Secret Name

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github repo that contains an action to call an azure devops pipeline.
Currently this works but it requires a personal access token to call the pipeline.

```
azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'
```

The problem is for auditing/ownership purposes I need to know who called the pipeline, at the moment whoever is the owner of the access token stored within the repo is the person that devops reports as the person that ran the pipeline. I also need to make each person responsible for updating their own tokens rather than 1 person.

My plan was to have each member of the team that uses the repo store a secret with the format `github username_AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN` I could then change the github action to reference that secret.

The problem I'm coming up against is that `'${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'` can't be constructed dynamically.
For example something like (I know this doesn't work) `${{ secrets.${{github.actor}} }}_AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'`

I've seen similar requests but their accepted answers (elsewhere) don't seem to work. This was suggested

```
env:
    devops_token: ${{ github.actor }}_AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN
 {..}
    azure-devops-token: '"${{ secrets[env.devops_token] }}"'
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT**
Additionally to the above, I now realise need to process the github.actor value before using it as they contain a hyphen which I can't use in a secret name.
This is how I'm currently testing, I've broken it out to 3 jobs just so I can check each part of the process works

```
    on:
  workflow_dispatch  

jobs:
  example-job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Replace string
      id: step_one
      run: |
        echo "user_underscore=$(echo ${{github.actor}} | tr '-' '_')" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step_one.outputs.user_underscore }}
  
  example-job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: example-job1
    steps:
    - name: lower to upper 
      env:
        INPUT1: ${{needs.example-job1.outputs.output1}}
      id: step_two
      run: |
        echo "user_upper=$(echo $INPUT1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    outputs:
      output2: ${{ steps.step_two.outputs.user_upper }}
      
  example-job3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: example-job2
    steps:
    - name: Get secret 
      env:
        INPUT2: ${{needs.example-job2.outputs.output2}}
      id: step_three
      run: |
        echo "$INPUT2"
        echo '"${{ secrets[format('{0}_DEVOPS_TOKEN', '$INPUT2')] }}"'}
        echo '"${{ secrets[format('{0}_DEVOPS_TOKEN', 'SOME_USERNAME')] }}"'
```

I don't think the issue is related to the processing of the username because when the 3rd job runs `echo "$INPUT2"` displays the username with an underscore and in caps and `'echo '"${{ secrets[format('{0}_DEVOPS_TOKEN', 'SOME_USERNAME')] }}"'` displays *** which is what I'm expecting.

However `echo '"${{ secrets[format('{0}_DEVOPS_TOKEN', '$INPUT2')] }}"'` comes back with `""`

Comment: Did you try using `format` with your last snippet? Example: `azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets[format("{0}_AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN", github.actor] }}'`

Comment: @Azeem I had tried that but I've gone back and tested it, it still doesn't work but I hardcoding the username instead of github.actor and it works. I've tried lots of different ways of passing a variable instead of a string and they all fail.

Comment: Did you look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255989/dynamically-retrieve-github-actions-secret)? I just noticed that in my comment above, the closing parenthesis is missing for `format()`. Could you please update your question with what you tried using `format()`? Seems like it should work.

Comment: @Azeem added some more information and I had seen that thread since posting,

Comment: Try [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxtj1tLw0AQhd/zKw5LYFsw4vOCBa2hSqEpTexLKSENI1Xb3WUvSknz382NiODLcIYz880ZJQW0t8cg+FAHKwKgfG8rYLy0kWpsf/DS+ehUOLKus6wjbfupCLI4k8DakC4MIaXSkMOSLp3dYQSuQwN80uWehRMqjwosXLxkz6+P+cM8SzYMVzgDHnHwnA/NTpzUNxmx5632Wnd6ykZeD2qpYVMYZrNfbLzasuBPykUTrU84AEh+iZGVxvNNnAmEVQXbTdndmzLnwk14dVfnT/E2Wad5lizjFb9pd2+bm9M96vr/Z/twI7YXLPgBgIRlng==).

Comment: @Azeem that worked..... not sure what I was doing wrong, I even checked with `echo secrets[format('{0}_DEVOPS_TOKEN', '$INPUT2')]` and that came back with `secrets[format('{0}_DEVOPS_TOKEN', 'SOME_USERNAME'` but still didn't work.
Thank you very much